# Can you kick bots mid-game?

Tags: gtfo

Me and my two friends were playing a level in GTFO and after many grueling hours of struggling, we made it to the last part of the level which involved holding out against a horde of enemies while waiting for a slow security scan, after which we had to sprint to the exit and perform yet another security scan in the process.

Our issue was that during the first long security scan, our 4th player (a computer controlled bot) was bringing us down.  Security scans only progress if **all** players in the game are "up" (i.e. not needing to be revived).  Naturally, the bot isn't the *best* at staying safe, and it would constantly go down on us.  Even when we managed to finish the long security scan with the bot standing, there was no way we could finish the level due to the next security scan where all of us were in pretty bad shape (the bot wouldn't even make it to the next scan without getting downed).  We ultimately decided to quit the level, losing all our progress made, and wasting our evening.

GTFO is an extremely cooperative oriented 4-player game.  You can choose to sub in bots for unfilled human players, or go as a 3-player team which puts you at a serious disadvantage, or you could also use matchmaking.  But, it could be useful to have a bot up to a certain point in a level, at which point you could decide if you want to kick them or not.  However, I couldn't find a way to do so.  Is it possible to kick bots mid-game, and if so, how?

Comment: from [fandom](https://gtfo.fandom.com/wiki/Bots): They can also be added and removed inside an ongoing expedition. Thanks to the communication menu, by pressing Q (default key), you can manage your bots. Not writing an answer because I don't know if this is right/it works. So try and let us know? ^^

Comment: @CesarM I don't recall seeing an option there for removing the  bot... but I'll have to check.  I thought the Q commands were just for using non-vocal communications between teammates (and also to direct the bot to a degree).